GeoServer EKS pod memory isssue
I am currently running Kartoza/GeoServer helm chart deployed to EKS (GeoServer version 2.24.0).
We previously had a Linux deployment in production and migrated to EKS now. We're using EFS for data storage and it contains over 3TB of data.
We have configured limits in helm chart with 4 cpus and 30Gb RAM. When pod is in Ready state, it's already consuming a lot of RAM, almost 50%(15GB). But when we check the GeoServer UI in server status tab, it shows only a few GBs of RAM is in use.
At the time of taking the following screenshot, the GeoServer pod RAM usage is at 20GB.

This pod is running on an EC2 instance of T3.2xlarge type. This has 32GB RAM and 8vCPUs.
The following is the statistics from the GeoServer UI system status page:

Operating System: Ubuntu 20.04.6 LTS Physical CPUs: 4 Logical CPUs: 8 Running Processes: 1 Running Threads: 626 CPU Load Average: 3.64% Memory Used: 76.44% (Total Memory: 31.0 GiB, Free Memory: 7.3 GiB) Swap Used: 0% (Total Swap: 0 B) File System Usage: 16.15% (Partition /: 49.2 GiB total, 41.3 GiB free) GeoServer Specific:
GeoServer CPU Usage: 0.00% GeoServer Threads: 122 GeoServer JVM Memory Usage: 72.91%

The processes running inside the pod also shows geoserver process consuming close to 18GB of memory.
We have tried reducing the JAI Maximum memory configuration on our dev environment to see if the memory usage on startup decreases, but that didn't make a difference.

how much memory have you assigned to the JVM in your start up configuration?

@IanTurton In the values.yaml file we've given this for pod env vars: extraPodEnv: |

name: INITIAL_MEMORY
value: "20G"
name: MAXIMUM_MEMORY
value: "30G".  Are these value corresponding to min and max JVM memory allocation?


I've no idea how your docker container is configured, you would need to talk to your supplier or maintenance contractor, or look at the actual config in the tomcat directory

@IanTurton From the documentation of the docker image I'm using(https://github.com/kartoza/docker-geoserver/blob/master/.env), it says the INITIAL_MEMORY and MAXIMUM_MEMORY correspond to JVM options -Xms and -Xmx, so they are for the initial and maximum heap memory.

that seems to answer your question then - you have allocated 20Gb to the JVM on start up and that is how much it is using

@IanTurton Thank you for your help. Just one further question, if the pod resource limit for memory is 30GB, should I assign 30GB as maximum heap memory in geoserver conf or should it be lowered?

I would avoid messing with any of these limits until you have read and understood the manual

Ok noted. Thank you for your help.@IanTurton
